# Application pool 'poolName' exceeded its job limit settings

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, iis-6, windows-server-2003

Since last few hours, on our test environment, I can see this message keeps appearing in "System" in Event Viewer.

It is coming after gap of 1 - 2 minutes.

Website is extremely slow too, when I go to few specific pages.

> Application pool 'poolName' exceeded its job limit settings.

**What could be possibly reason for it and how can I fix it.**

These errors came few days back too and more days too, I tried recycling app pool but nothing changed.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735237(v=ws.10).aspx and use IIS Debug Diagnostic tool.

Comment: Are you closing and disposing properly?  If you're not destroying your objects you mind find this is gobbling up your resources. (Just set the to nothing - `set myObj = nothing`).